# Passing stack variables to pthread_cleanup_push

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a thread that uses a file descriptor and must `close()` the file descriptor when cancelled.  The pseudocode looks like:

```
static void thread_cleanup(void *args)
{
    int *fd = (int *)args;
    close(*fd);
}

void *thread(void *arg)
{
    int fd = open(...);
    ...
    pthread_cleanup_push(thread_cleanup, &fd);
    ....
}
```

One option I had was to pass `fd` casted to a `void *` from `thread`, and have `thread_cleanup` cast it back to an `int`, but this may cause problems if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *)`.  My question is: is passing stack variables as in the pseudocode safe when used in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern about `sizeof` seems to be based on some confusion. No conversion between `int` and `void *` is taking place, so whether they are the same size, or whether the values of one can be represented in the other, is irrelevant. What's happening is that the address of `fd`, a pointer value of type `int *`, is being converted to `void *` and back to `int *`. This is the whole point of `void *` and is perfectly correct usage.

As for whether it matters that the pointed-to object is "on the stack" (an object with automatic storage duration in the function where the cleanup handler is pushed/popped), the answer is yes, but your usage is okay.

Formally (as the current specification in POSIX is written), any object whose lifetime did not end before cancellation was acted upon still exists and can be accessed from all the cleanup handlers. However, this seems to be a mistake in the standard, as it conflicts with the Rationale document which supports unwinding-based implementations (like most real-world implementations) where cancellation cleanup handlers execute at the block context where they were pushed. Since the object `int fd;` in the function `thread` has lifetime associated with the containing block outside the `pthread_cleanup_push` block, it's perfectly safe to access it from the cleanup handler `thread_cleanup`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  As for the `sizeof` concern, my original plan was to call `pthread_cleanup_push(thread_cleanup, (void *)fd)` and have `thread_cleanup` call `close((int)args)`.  I probably should have removed that part of my post entirely since it's not really relevant.

Comment: I see. Yes, that approach would depend on values of `int` surviving the round trip to `void *` and back. But with your approach it doesn't matter.